# Are there any advantages using a .NET Framework 4.0 dll instead of a 2.0 dll?

Tags: .net, optimization, compiler-construction, frameworks

In a similar topic of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759/are-there-any-advantages-compiling-for-net-framework-3-5-instead-of-2-0) I'm wondering whether there are any advantages for using a dll that is specifically compiled for .NET 4.

For example: log4net and nunit only officially release libraries that are compiled for .NET 2.0 but these work fine in a .NET 4.0 application. Is there an advantage of taking these libraries and re-compiling them for .NET 4.0?

Obviously the new features in the framework can be targetted by using the newer runtimes, but I'm talking about just straight re-compiling.

Comment: If you port it to 4.0 and it compiles fine, you are in the clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you recompile them using the C# 4 compiler, you will get various improvements in IL generation, including [field-like events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx) and [better `lock` statements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx).

You'll get some of these improvements even if you target .Net 2.0.